# Cannot acces the servlet file as apache is installed in local machine,what path should be given in form's action attribute?

Tags: java, servlets, localhost

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Home here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://@localhost:8080/webFirst/GetResult">
Enter USN<input type="text" name="USN">
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

I'm getting a **"resource not found error"**. Is the URL in form's action attribute correct? As my server is installed in local machine itself.

Comment: remove th `@` sign

Comment: @Jens  i tried it but same problem

Comment: It is hard to tell from the input given what the correct URL will be. You are saying that you get a resource not found, which does sound like somthing is responding on your server but nothing is mapped to the url `/webFirst/GetResult` you have specified. 

If you have a servlet which should respond to your form request it should consist of the context root of your application followed by the servlet mapping, something like `/contextRoot/MyServletMapping`. Since you haven't included any information about the context root or the servlet mapping it is hard to help you further.

Comment: usually you don't have to put in a full url, just the servlet mapping , ex `action="/GetResult"` and this servlet should be mapped either in web.xml or in the servlet class itself using Annotation, however, if you insist , you can use full url, but not `localhost` because once this form is opened by a client, `localhost` will point to there machines. you have to use your local ip, ex `192.168...` or a machine/domain name. but again this is bad practice. cuz you have to write your domain/ip in each html page, and if changed, it will be a big problem

Comment: http://loclhost:8080/webFirst/GetResult?USN=3v1234tcj  this is the url after clicking on submit button but its telling make sure the web address is correct

Comment: `localhost`. With an `a` between the `c` and the `l`. Not `loclhost`.

Comment: even if that worked for you, it will be because you opened the site from the machine that runs the http-server (apache), if some other machine opens the site it will not work. check answer below by Alex it's what i am talking about

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide much information. Here's an example:

```
<form id="MyForm" action="MyServlet" method="GET or POST">
```

In your Servlet:

```
 @WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"})
        public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
```